# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left\{\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n}\right\}\;,$ Where $n\in \mathbb{N}.$

Tags: calculus

Evaluation of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left\{\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n}\right\}\;,$ Where $n\in \mathbb{N}.$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n} = I +f\;,$$ where $0<f\leq 1$ and $I = $ Integer part.

Now  Let $$0<\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n}<1\;,$$ So $$\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n}=f'$$.

So $$\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n}+\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n} = I +f+f' = \bf{Integer\; Quantity.}$$

So $$f+f'\in \mathbb{Z}.$$ Now Given $0<(f+f')<2$. So $f+f' = 1\in \mathbb{Z}$

So $$I+f+f' = \bf{Integer\; Quantity}\Rightarrow f = Integer\; Quantity-f'$$

So $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left\{\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n}\right\} = \bf{Integer\; quantity-}\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left\{\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n}\right\}$$

Now how can i solve after that, help me, Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but doesn't $2+\sqrt{3}>1$ imply the limit is infinity?

Comment: Does { _a_ } mean the fractional part of _a_ ?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $\{x\}$ means the fractional part of $x$.

You know that for every $n \in \Bbb N$,
$$\left\{(2 + \sqrt{3})^{2n}\right\} + (2 - \sqrt{3})^{2n} = 1.$$

Since $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(2 - \sqrt{3})^{2n} = 0,$$
it follow that  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\{(2 + \sqrt{3})^{2n}\right\} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $I\in\mathbb N,0\le f\le1$ and
$$Z=\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n}=I+f$$
Let $Z'=(2-\sqrt3)^{2n}$ so $0\le (2-\sqrt3)^{2n}\le1$
Now:
$$Z+Z'=I+f+Z'=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^k(\sqrt3)^{2n-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^k(-\sqrt3)^{2n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^k[(\sqrt3)^{2n-k}+(-\sqrt3)^{2n-k}]=2^0(2(3)^{n})+2^2(2(3)^{n-1})+\ldots$$
Clearly $Z+Z'\in\mathbb {2N}$

So: $f+Z'\in\mathbb N$ and since $0\le f+Z'\le2\implies f+Z'=1\implies Z\in\mathbb{2N-1}$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}Z'=0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}f=1$

Answer (score 1):

You have all the necessary ideas around; you need to connect them a little better.

You know that $0<2-\sqrt3<1$. This implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2-\sqrt3)^{2n}=0$.

You also know that $(2+\sqrt3)^{2n}+(2-\sqrt3)^{2n}\in\mathbb Z$ for all $n$. So $$(2+\sqrt3)^{2n}=M_n-(2-\sqrt3)^{2n}$$
for appropriate integers $M_n$. Then
$$
\{(2+\sqrt3)^{2n}\}= 1-(2-\sqrt3)^{2n},
$$
and then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\{(2+\sqrt3)^{2n}\}=1.$$